# Joining a table where values lie between values from consecutive rows in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

What is the cleanest way to populate the 3rd column in the FINAL TABLE based on the following logic:

Assign `B.appears` to the 'upper' record in `TABLE A` if `B.id` falls between 2 consecutive `A.id` records.

```
TABLE A

id          text
----------- ------------------
422         a
473         b
526         c
577         d




TABLE B

id          appears
----------- ------------------
465         yes
569         yes




FINAL TABLE SHOULD SHOW:

id          text               appears
----------- ------------------ ---------------------
422         a                  yes
473         b
526         c                  yes
577         d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is full working example with your data with comments and output from each sub-query. You are free to break it in separated statements using table variable or temp table:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @A TABLE
    (
         [ID] SMALLINT
        ,[Text] CHAR(1)
    )

    DECLARE @B TABLE
    (
         [ID] SMALLINT
        ,[Text] CHAR(3)
    )

    INSERT INTO @A ([ID], [Text])
    VALUES (422,'a')
          ,(473,'b')
          ,(526,'c')
          ,(577,'d')

    INSERT INTO @B ([ID], [Text])
    VALUES (465,'yes')
          ,(569,'yes')

    ;WITH DataSource ([RowID], [ID], [Text]) AS 
    (   -- Adding row id to each record
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ID] ASC) AS Row, [ID], [Text]
        FROM @A
        /*
            RowID   ID  Text
            1       577 d
            2       473 b
            3       426 c
            4       422 a
        */
    ), TempSource ( [CurrentID], [NextID], [CurrentText]) AS
    (
        -- Getting the "Next" id of each record
        SELECT DS1.[ID]
              ,DS2.[ID]
              ,DS1.[Text] 
        FROM DataSource DS1
        LEFT JOIN DataSource DS2
            ON DS1.[RowID] + 1 = DS2.[RowID]
        /*
            CurrentID   NextID  CurrentText
            577         473     d
            473         426     b
            426         422     c
            422         NULL    a
        */
    )
    SELECT TS.[CurrentID] AS [ID]
          ,TS.[CurrentText] AS [Text]
          ,B.[Text] AS [Appears]
    FROM TempSource TS
    LEFT JOIN @B AS B
        ON TS.[CurrentID] < B.[ID]
        AND TS.[NextID] > B.[ID]
    ORDER BY TS.[CurrentID]
    /*
        ID  Text    Appears
        422 a       yes
        473 b       NULL
        526 c       yes
        577 d       NULL
    */

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server 2012, there is a very clean method:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE ( id int, txt char(1) )
INSERT @A VALUES (422,'a'),(473,'b'),(526,'c'),(577,'d')

DECLARE @B TABLE ( id int, appears char(1) )
INSERT @B VALUES (465,'Y'), (569,'Y')

SELECT
  A.id,
  A.txt,
  B.appears
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    txt,
    LEAD(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS next_id
  FROM @a
) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN @B B ON (B.id BETWEEN A.id AND A.next_id)
```

If not, you'll need to use a subquery or self-join:

```
  ...
  SELECT
    id,
    txt,
    (SELECT MIN(id) FROM @a WHERE id > a1.id) AS next_id
  FROM @a a1
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately I am running 2008R2.